# How to perform aggregation in tablueu

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I have a pretty simple use case,but do not know how shall I do it in Tableau 10. 
I have following column as a dimension

```
Emails
gmail
gmail
hotmail
Hotmail
GMAIL
HOTMAIL
```

I just want to count no. of occurances of emails.

```
gmail     3
hotmail   3
```

I also need to convert all the text to lowercase and then count no of occurances.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert to lowercase

Create a calculated field(Analysis->Create Calculated Field),I'm going to call it "lowercase_email", and use the function LOWER to convert the emails text to lowecase:

```
 LOWER([Emails])
```

2. Drag this new calculated field, "lowercase email", into the rows shelf and it will automatically group the emails by the unique names, add the measure of number of records, and it will count the number per email.

Comment: If you also want to combine other variants or mispellings, then create a group based on the original Emails field (for example, multi-select the values that you want to treat as identical, and press the paperclip icon to group them together)